# Ubuntu MATE starts w/o task bars or icons

Tags: ubuntu-mate

When I login to my Ubuntu MATE system after a hard reboot, I don't get any task bars or icons.  Sometimes this resolves with a another hard boot, and sometimes I have to go through two hard boots.

Any ideas of what I should be looking for to fix this?

Comment: Did you see 1502694.  Maybe fix the xorg.conf